# Plotly Graphs. Show data on graph instead of getting it from hovering

Tags: python, plotly

Is there any way to show the data on the graph instead of hovering data.

Comment: **text** does this for you.  what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

- **text** parameters can be used
- below example shows `hover_data=["info", "cat"]` and then including on figure as text with `texttemplate="%{customdata[0]}<br>%{customdata[1]}"`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# fmt: off
words = ['adipisci', 'aliquam', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'dolor', 'dolore', 'dolorem', 'eius', 'est', 'etincidunt', 'ipsum', 'labore', 'magnam', 'modi', 'neque', 'non', 'numquam', 'porro', 'quaerat', 'quiquia', 'quisquam', 'sed', 'sit', 'tempora', 'ut', 'velit', 'voluptatem']

df = pd.DataFrame({"year": np.repeat(range(2011, 2021), 2), "cat": np.tile(list("AB"), 10),
                   "val": np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 20), "info": np.random.choice(words, 20)})
# fmt: on

px.bar(
    df,
    x="year",
    y="val",
    color="cat",
    text="val",
    barmode="group",
    hover_data=["info", "cat"],
).update_traces(
    texttemplate="%{customdata[0]}<br>%{customdata[1]}", textposition="outside"
).update_layout(
    xaxis_type="category", yaxis_tickformat=".1%", yaxis_range=[-1.2, 1.2]
)
```

[image]